# Django /admin/ doesn't accept correct credentials. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, django

This question was asked multiple times already, but I didn't find solution so far.
All the [requirements from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) are satisfied already. I created superuser (`python manage.py createsuperuser`). Then I ran command `manage.py runserver`, went to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and entered login and password for newly created superuser. And I'm receiving error message:

`Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`

Why? I tried to recreate superuser, change password, create different superuser just in case there are inacceptible characters with as simple credentials, as possible, but still the same result. What's wrong with that? How do I fix this?

I'm using Windows 10, PyCharm, Python 3.7, Django 2.2.3.

P.S. Even more strange thing: I tried to delete database (default NoSQL file) and migrations, recreate database from scratch with `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate` and when I did `runserver` after that via windows terminal, I could still use superuser credentials and gain access to admin panel. I thought superuser credentials are stored in the same database. Then I checked Windows 10 network credentials in control panel, but there are no records of my superuser. That's one heck of a mystery here for me so far. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: how did you create the super user?

Comment: you need to create super user first with `python manage.py createsuperuser` in your terminal or go into your database and check user table

Comment: I did create superuser. I wrote about it. Yes, I was using command `python manage.py createsuperuser`. Sorry for confution: I used shell to edit and recreate superuser on further attempts after first one failed. (I edited question).

Comment: Are you using a custom user model? In a shell can you retrieve your user from the DB? `python manage.py shell` -> `from django.contrib.auth.models import User; print(User.objects.all())`

Comment: Can you share your setting `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`?

Comment: "Are you using a custom user model?" - No. "In a shell can you retrieve your user from the DB?" - Strange, but yes and no. When I type command `python manage.py createsuperuser` and type again same name it says that it's taken, your command prints list with user I created before, but db viewer shows empty table `auth_users`. What's going on?

Comment: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` - I don't have it in settings.py. Should I? It's not listed in Django docs as requirement to use admin panel.

Comment: Strange: when I run `python manage.py runserver` from terminal as admin - everything works and I can enter admin panel. But when I do the same via PyCharm (even if i run it as admin) - gives me error with wrong credentials. Interpreter path and script path are the same in both cases. And in shell, launched via PyCharm `print(User.objects.all())` prints empty list. O_o

Comment: Can you share your DATABASES setting? maybe you have multiple depending on where you run the server from?

Comment: No, only one default record in this setting (`sqlite3`). I didn't change DATABASES setting after Django install. `DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}`

Comment: Does password contain non-alphabet characters? Try with simple password - only digits or letters. It may be encoding, i.e. in terminal you have `utf8` while in browser `windows-1252` and even though characters look same they are not.

Comment: I don't think it's encoding: if it was it, I wouldn't be able to login at all, but I'm able to login from browser when I run server from terminal command and I can't login in browser when I run server from PyCharm. And I've been trying simple letters only login and digits only password just in case. Didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resolved by adding the default django back end after accidentally over writing it.

settings.py

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAuthCodeBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: I've already switched to C# from Python and I'm working as a C# developer for more then 3 years and I don't remember how did I manage this issue back then. But thanks for the answer anyway. :)